# CDF(X)^2 versus CDF(X^2): What's the difference?

Tags: distributions, python, descriptive-statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

To explain clearly what my question is imagine this simple example.
*"There are 101 boxes each numbered 1,2,3... and so on. An android can randomly choose one of these boxes, but each one with a probability proportional to its number."*

```
import numpy as np
from empiricaldist import Pmf, Cdf
```

> NB: The function Pmf() from empiricaldist simply creates a pandas series with a convenient .normalize() method.
> Cdf() works similarly. You don't need to know these functions to follow the question.

The PMF of the event of choosing a box is `Px`

```
Px = np.linspace(0,1, 101)
Px = Pmf(Px)
Px.normalize()
```

While the PMF of the event of choosing 2 times the same box is `Px2`

```
Px2 = Pmf(px**2)
```

[image: PMF distributions]
Now I can compute 2 CDF one for each event

```
Cx = Px.make_cdf()
Cx2 = Px2.make_cdf()
```

But I can also calculate the following distribution

```
Cx_2 = Cx**2
```

[image: CDF distributions]

Now my question is: how to interpret Cx2 and Cx_2?
Each probability of a quantity 'Q' of Cx can be interpreted as the probability of choosing a box with value equal or lower than Q.
For Cx2 each value is the probability of choosing twice a box with the same value lower than Q.
How can be Cx_2 interpreted since it is different from Cx2?
Can it be the probability of choosing twice a box with a value lower then Q but not necessarily the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, but seems to ask about the difference between:

- The probability of seeing $x$ or less in both of the two draws, your yellow `Cx_2` CDF curve, i.e. $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2) \le x)$
- The conditional probability of seeing $x$ or less in both of the two draws given that both draws are the same, your green `Cx2` curve, i.e. $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2) \le x\mid X_1=X_2)$

They are different distributions, and you are more likely to see a larger number in the first (i.e. the yellow curve is to the right of the green curve).  In the first $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2)=1)\approx 0.0000000377$ and $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2)=101)\approx 0.0388$, while in the second $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2)=1 \mid X_1=X_2)\approx 0.00000287$ and $\mathbb P(\max(X_1,X_2)=101\mid X_1=X_2)\approx 0.0293$

Note that neither of these are the CDF of $X^2$, which would have support on the values $1,4,9,\ldots, 10201$, and would have $\mathbb P(X^2=1)=\mathbb P(X=1)\approx 0.000194$ and $\mathbb P(X^2=10201)=\mathbb P(X=101)\approx 0.0196$